# Password protect an app so only specific users can create an account

Tags: passwords

Trying to avoid User ID's and matching correct ID's, looking at 200+ users, and that can be a mess.  Is there a way for there to be a PW required prior to downloading the app?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please edit your question with the platform and language(s) are you using. With so little context it is nearly impossible to answer this question.